# Protobuf's oneof keyword in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, protocol-buffers, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio seems to support *proto* files. However, the `oneof` keyword gives an error and the tooltip displays *unexpected token*. How to fix this?

Android Studio version is 0.8.4 and I have the dependency `compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.0'` in my application gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in Android Studio's syntax highlighter -- it probably hasn't been updated for the recent Protobuf 2.6.0 release, which introduced `oneof`. You should file a bug against the syntax highlighter (or maybe just against Android Studio). Note that the error is only in the editor -- your actual code is (probably) fine, and will build fine.